# cuffdiff 2.2.1 with Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: segmentation-fault

please give me some help! I had struggled with the problem for a long time.
my script and output:

> perfect_match_hit bioinformatic$ cuffdiff -L wt,tg -p 20 -o cuffdiffOutputS /usr/local/Mus_musculus_UCSC_mm10/Mus_musculus/UCSC/mm10/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf \
>   perfect_hits_WT1.bam,perfect_hits_WT2.bam \
>   perfect_hits_tKO1.bam,perfect_hits_tKO2.bam,perfect_hits_tKO3.bam 
>   You are using Cufflinks v2.2.1, which is the most recent release.
>
> [18:30:07] Loading reference annotation.
>
> [18:30:13] Inspecting maps and determining fragment length distributions.

Segmentation fault: 11

I am using cufflinks 2.2.1, boost 1.55.01 under homebrew, os x 10.10.5 with Xcode 7.2.

Most weird things were that I can use cuffdiff if I tried a very small .bam file and no replicates, but didn't work if I tried any bigger(more that 100 MB) or more than 1 replicates. 
I tried boost 1.58.0,1.59 even 1.60, also lower version, failed. 
My computer's memory is 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. So I don't think it's memory ability.

Please give me some idea. A little bit crazy now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try -p 1 and yes I know it's slow.

Comment: I started with using -p 1, but it seemed whatever number I put after -p didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try reverting to cufflinks 2.1.1. This cured the problem of the program throwing segmentation errors with two different datasets I had — paired ends and unpaired ends. In no circumstances would I now use 2.2.